# Using the Marshal module to serialize ver 1.8 Class objects, load into 2.2 script

Tags: ruby, serialization, deserialization, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have some serialized objects that were created with a 1.8 ruby script. I would like to be able to use Marshal to load these objects into a new script that is written with newer versions of ruby (2.2 and up). In order for Marshal to be able to load these objects, it needs to know the data footprint of these objects, which are all custom class defined in the 1.8 script. However, when I `require` the 1.8 script, it throws syntax errors as there were many syntax changes between these two ruby versions. I would rather not manually go through the old script and fix every syntax error since the script is quite long.

Instead, I thought that I could use Marshal to serialize the custom `Class` objects that were defined in the 1.8 script and then load them into the 2.2 script. Once the 2.2 script knows about those classes, it could then load the original serialized objects that are instances of the recently loaded classes. All this is to save myself the work of manually bringing the old script up to date.

One problem I can see is that the `Class` class may not be the same between 1.8 and 2.2, and therefore the 2.2 script could not deserialize the `Class` objects from the 1.8 script. Does anyone know if the `Class` class differs from 1.8 to 2.2? Is there a way I can work around this?

What is the best way to view all the `Class` objects available in a ruby script so that I can serialize them?

An obvious solution is to just write my new script in ruby 1.8 but this is not what I want to do because newer versions of ruby have features and fixes that I want to utilize.

Comment: What syntax errors are you getting? There are breaking changes between 1.8 and 2.2 but I can't think of any breaking syntax changes.

Comment: I get problems with switch statements, invalid multibyte escape, invalid break.